# Rails Marketplace - Spree Gem or Build from Scratch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I wish to create a marketplace using rails. Currently, there is a ecommerce gem called Spree and I am planning to use it.

BUT a dilemma is stopping me from pursuing it. I am mixed as to whether I should build the marketplace from scratch or build it faster using Spree and its extensions.

I simply want to build an mvp and this is what I gather...

(1) Using the Spree gem will be faster but again, it might be difficult to customize or pivot.
(2) Building from scratch might be slow but I will always be in control of the features of the site. 
(3) Some spree extensions are not well maintained.

I hope to seek opinions regarding this. And I hope to get some. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Spree will give you a lot of boilerplate code you will need. Then you can write the plugins that you need. Writing plugins compared to writing Spree like gem would take less time and effort.

Answer (score 4):

I get your concerns about customizability. Well, it would help if you just looked at it this way : I will first build my Rails app (no Spree yet), do all the stuff I want to do - eg authorization, API integrations etc. Then just when you want to add the Model for the products you want to sell, instead of doing a custom Product model, just add Spree gem and it will create a customizable Product model with all the related stuff in a few commands.

Then you can go on adding all the remaining app Models in your app, totally unrelated to the Spree gem. I've done it once before.

So just jump in. After all, it will still be easy to pivot. When it doesn't work, you just remove Spree gem and the rest of your Rails app remains as it is. You can now build your custom Product models. Easy

Answer (score 1):

Spree is written in a way that's intended to make it easy to customize.

The code is all available to view, customize, and override, so you will stay in control of your site.

While extensions are not always maintained well, they at least provide a good starting point so you don't have to implement the feature from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build an MVP and stay with Ruby on Rails, then your best option is to use open source version of [Sharetribe](https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe). We have done tens of custom online and mobile marketplaces and for some clients started with Sharetribe. This option gives you ALL you need in the box for typical peer-to-peer marketplace while you have all the freedom for customization. It is open source Ruby on Rails in github. We publish series of posts on marketplace development including what you need to start with sharetribe, http://syndicode.co/ruby-on-rails-marketplace-development/. Please feel free to reach to me if you have some questions, need advise or feasibility of Sharetribe for your specific idea.